# Finalizing CD after burning a Disc

Tags: windows, windows-7

I just burned an audio CD on my Windows 7.  How to finalize?  I cannot find any topics.  The burned CD will not play on other machines.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What was the process you used to "[burn the] audio CD"?

Comment: When you inserted the disk into your computer, a dialogue box was shown, offering you 2 options.  Which option did you choose? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Try this software>>>>https://cdburnerxp.se/en/home

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use Power2Go software for CD-DVD burning on my windows 7 computer. The application may help because it gives an option to "close" the disk and validate that all contents are on there and allows capability for the disk to be read on most devices

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you use Explorer to create a CD or DVD, when you eject the CD or DVD, windows will automatically close that session for you. This however is all explorer can do.

Keep in mind, just dragging and dropping files onto your disc is not enough. You have to click burn to add them. If you see the files as semi-transparent items, then this means you have not yet burned the files/audio to the CD yet and as such the disc session is not closed upon ejecting either as there is no need to.

To actually finalize the CD or DVD, you have to use burning software that can finalize the CD or DVD for you. After that, it can be used on older standalone players.

Modern players can play discs that are not finalized though, you may want to test if you actually need to finalize the disc.

Comment: Modern versions of Windows, which might or might not include Windows 7, has the ability to finalize the session depending on the option that is selected.  The author didn't indicate what the "other machines" are exactly, if they are Windows machines, the built-in burn capability should have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

These "other machines" are specifically older devices that have a less advanced cd drive and thus can't read the cd without a cd "root", this is the section of the cd that tells the drive where the files are on the disk. Finishing the cd adds this "root" to the cd